# Powershell webinvoke with Google Script webapp

Tags: powershell, google-apps-script

Is there a way to web invoke from PowerShell connection to web app created in google app script ?

When im running the request on normal sites I will receive back information containing Forms[], Images[], InputFields[] etc. However when I'm trying to run the same request on a https://script.google.com/a/macros/ web app all those fields are blank and i can only see a variable called el linking to field called sandboxFrame.

The app is a simple upload site to one of my google folders, everything is working when I'm in browser. I'm trying to automate the process through PowerShell script

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<input type='button' value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()'>
</body>

<script>
function getFiles() {
  const f = document.getElementById('files');
  [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
        console.log(id);
      }).saveFile(obj);
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
</script>
</html>
```

GS script

```
    function saveFile(obj) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1w586veZcOZN_NnB90jaTZ12DF-jP005u');
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  return folder.createFile(blob).getId();
}
```

Comment: Can you invoke an http or https request in your version power shell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You would need to take advantage of the `doPost` function.

I assume you already know about the `doGet` function, but there is another function that you can use as part of a web app called `doPost`. This allows you to post data using something like the following from powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://script.google.com/a/macros/[SCRIPTID]?[QUERYSTRING] -Method POST
```

Where the `[QUERYSTRING]` is something like:

```
name=bartosz&stack=BartoszWolas&reputation=1000
```

Then within the `doPost` on the web app side you would write a function like this:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const name = e.parameter.name; // bartosz
  const stackAlias = e.parameter.stack; // BartoszWolas
  const reputation = e.parameter.reputation; // 1000
}
```

#### Reference

- [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: That worked like a charm thanks for help and i do believe I will manage to post some files using this and encode to base64, thanks for help